# Importing data from different SQL Server to another when trigger fires

Tags: sql-server, import, synchronization, database-connection, relational-database

I need to create a trigger on one server to fire when a certain table is changed, after which I have to do some calculation with the data so I can import (it's no just copying) it into another table on a different server.

Also I only want to import the new data that hasn't been imported through a earlier trigger.

How would I go about this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Does the data need to be injected into the other server in real time? If there can be a delay, what is your tolerance? 5 seconds? A minute?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2. We could tolerate 10 seconds of delay.

Answer (score 0):

Create `Linked Server` to your target server, then use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to perform action depending on existence of record in destination table.
I would refrain from creating triggers referring remote servers though, it might have performance and reliability implications. Consider using `Service Broker` if you want to achieve small latency and still make the update reliable.

Comment: How would you know when to do the merging if there is no trigger?

Comment: There would still be a trigger, but not writing data synchronously to remote server, it would send changed data to `Service Broker` which would be then processed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked server between two SQL Servers to send data from one to the other.

To create a linked server you need to use the system stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver, you can also do it through SQL Server Management Studio I believe.

Here is an example you can try:

```
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver @server=N'serverip/hostname', @provider=N'SQLNCLI'
```

You can view if your linked server has been created by querying sys.servers

You can query the linked server database with the following syntax:

```
SELECT x
FROM [linkedservername].[database].[schema].[table]
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

For the trigger updating only data which hasn't been handled before. There are many ways you can do this. If your source table has an 'update date' type column, you can do it based on that. Alternatively, if your table has an identity column and you want to copy data incrementally you can store in a table the 'last id' which is copied over each time, then on the next run of the trigger you can tell it to start from that id+1 that way rows are only transferred once.